# Data type error with bn.fit() in R: variable is not supported in bnlearn (type: integer)

Tags: r, bayesian, bnlearn

Based on a given network structure, I created a data frame of 100 instances for six binary variables(x1 to x6). So it's a 100 x 6 data frame of 0/1 values stored in a variable 'input_params'. Created an empty graph using statements:

`library(bnlearn)
 bn_graph = empty.graph(names(input_params))`

But when I try fitting above parameters('input_params') in the network using

`bn_nw <- bn.fit(bn_graph, input_params)`

I get an error saying
`Error in data.type(x) : 
  variable x1 is not supported in bnlearn (type: integer).`

What data type conversion should I do to avoid this error? Right now its 0 or 1 in the values.

Comment: The data type must be either numeric or factor. If your data are 0 / 1 's, they are likely categories. so if your data.frame is called dat use `dat[] <- lapply(dat, as.factor)`

Comment: This works, should put it as answer.

Answer (score 2):

The function `bn.fit()` in the package `bnlearn` calculates a local conditional probability distribution for each variable.

In the discrete case we expect `categorical` ([factor function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/factor)) parameters (in the columns `"fac1","fac2","fac3"`) :
`fac_cols <- c("fac1","fac2","fac3")`

Is is the data continous (e.g. measurements from a sensor) the data needs to be of type `numeric` ([numeric function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/numeric)):

`num_cols <- c("num1","num2","num3")`

Assuming `input_params` is a data.frame, we need to transform both sets of columns (`fac_cols`, `num_cols`) by either:

```
input_params[,fac_cols] <- lapply(input_params[,fac_cols], as.factor)
input_params[,num_cols] <- lapply(input_params[,num_cols], as.numeric)
```

or with `dplyr`

```
input_params <- input_params %>% mutate_at(vars(fac_cols), funs(as.factor)) %>% mutate_at(vars(num_cols), funs(as.numeric))
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to change qualitative variable names to one character, for example you have a variable name Age with categories young, adult, old. Now change names of subgroups to y,a,o
I have a problem like you and solved

Comment: This is not correct

Comment: ... and to give a counter example; the variables in the `alarm` dataset that comes with `bnlearn` have levels with more than one character (`library(bnlearn); data("alarm"); str(alarm)`)